# If all $a_n \geq 0$, what does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}<\infty$ imply on the $a_n$'s?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If all $a_n \geq 0$, what does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}<\infty$ imply on the $a_n$'s? In particular, does it imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$?

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$?

Comment: @abiessu : I guess $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$ does not come into picture as he wants the sum to converge..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I wrote that sum as one that the OP should use to compare to so that the questions can be answered.

Comment: @abiessu : I am sorry, I did not understand your intention.. If you think that will help OP, it is welcome... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $$a_n = \begin{cases} 1, & n=k^2, \\ 1/n, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Think about $a_n=1$ if $n$ is a power of $2$, and $a_n=0$ otherwise.

**Remark** If the $a_n$ are monotone non-increasing, then indeed $\lim a_n=0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And if $a_n \geq 0$, $\lim a_n=0$, does that imply $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}<\infty$?

Comment: No, the standard example is $\sum_3^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$, which diverges by the Integral Test.

Comment: @oliver : Nice Question...

Comment: @AndréNicolas : Great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. $\infty>\sum\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum\limits_1^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ with $a_n=0$ if $n$ isn't a perfect square, $a_n=1$ if $n$ is a perfect square.
You can conclude that $\lim\inf\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ though, since the harmonic series diverges.